# Express built-in parser returns empty req.body

Tags: node.js, express

This question is addressed ad nauseum on SO, but they all seem to tell people to use `body-parser`.

I'm trying to use the built-in parser in Express, rather than `body-parser`, since `body-parser` was re-added into Express 4.x so now they're the same thing.

However I'm getting an empty `req.body` with either `multipart/form-data` or `x-www-urlencoded` on both the HTML form and from Postman (resulting in "incorrect username or password" from passport, but that's a separate issue):

```js
const express = require('express');
require('dotenv');
const passport = require('passport');
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const User = require('../models/user');

passport.initialize();
// CHANGE: USE "createStrategy" INSTEAD OF "authenticate"
passport.use(User.createStrategy());
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

require('mongoose-type-url');

//connect to database
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL,{
    useNewUrlParser:true, 
    useUnifiedTopology:true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  useCreateIndex:true
}).then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to Mongo DB');
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('Mongoose error: ',err);
});
 
const app = express();
/* This is where npx express-generator automatically created the 'app.use' 
lines for the input parsers, both for json and urlencoded. 
I haven't touched this, it should be working just fine */
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(require('cookie-parser')());
app.use(require('express-session')({
  secret:"more things in the world",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
 
app.post('/login', testPostLogin);

// POST /login
async function testPostLogin(req, res, next) {
  const {username, password } = req.body;
  const { user, error } = await User.authenticate()(username, password);
  if(!user && error) {
      return next(error);
  }
  req.login(user, function (err) {
      if(err){
          return next(err);
      }
      req.session.success = `Welcome back, ${username}`;
      /*if they came to the login page from somewhere that called 'isLoggedIn', 
      send them back there after logging in, then remove the hook to do that */
      const redirectUrl = req.session.redirectTo || '/';
      delete req.session.redirectTo;
      res.redirect(redirectUrl);
  });
}

let port = process.env.PORT;
if (port == null || port == "") {
  port = 8080;
}
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("server has started, listening on port "+port);
});
```

Postman curl:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/login' \
--header 'Cookie: connect.sid=s%3A0aRKbFHVGSiUk-53HCZjuHKqYFAHIV7j.H9SDAJEDwY4rla2K%2BQ7ejiIJCMekMvhyeU8IH1sIh%2BE' \
--form 'username="bob"' \
--form 'password="password"'
```

Am I missing something stupidly obvious in my setup that is preventing express from parsing the body of the `POST` request?

UPDATE 2021-01-26 16:04 CST: I tried subbing in `body-parser` just to see what would happen, and still zilch. So is the issue that the middleware isn't being called on the route? Does that mean there's something wrong in my order of requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you read [body-parser documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) it's not possible, you should use third party module

> This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in the following modules:
>
> busboy and connect-busboy, multiparty and connect-multiparty, formidable,
> multer

If your form isn't sending any actual `multipart` information, only text, the `express.urlencoded()` should be able to parse it if sent with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` headers

Comment: I could have absolutely **sworn** that I had already tried encoding as `x-www-form-urlencoded` but apparently not. That's what I needed. Do you want to edit your answer, or should I answer it myself?

Answer (score 0):

Besides the solutions with formidable, there is another module which I have been using in my recent projects since 2019. The module [express-form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-form-data) can be easily declared in your server file like:

```
const formData = require('express-form-data');
app.use(formData.parse());

async function testPostLogin(req, res, next) {
  const {username, password } = req.body;
}
```

The above is going to work with `x-www-form-urlencoded` and json but it will NOT work with any `multipart`. `form-data` is also multipart with the header `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: I'd rather not bring in another module for this, since it's *supposed* to be built-in with Express now